# Syntax of JSON - Body Post request - SWIFT4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, post, httprequest

I am trying to fetch JSON using an HTTP Post request from the server but I think the body of my request is wrong. I tried everything and can't find a solution. The app is crashing.

I tried some different syntax on the body of the request (newTodo variable) like:

> '{"api_key":"mykey123","api_secret":"asdfg","uniqueid":"csd23cdse34ww","password":"secret123","pin":"12345"}'

and

> ["api_key": "mykey123", "api_secret": "asdfg","uniqueid": "csd23cdse34ww","password": "secret123","pin": "12345"]

Using the above I have the error:

> ["api_key": "mykey123", "password": "flibble1", "uniqueid": "csd23cdse34ww", "api_secret": "secret123", "pin": "12345"]
>   2019-01-25 10:00:54.298086+0000 APPTEST[8863:646933] [logging] table "users" already exists
>   table "users" already exists (code: 1) .
>   error parsing response from POST on /todos

Works fine on Postman with the body

> '{
>       "api_key": "mykey123",
>       "api_secret": "asdfg",
>       "uniqueid": "csd23cdse34ww",
>       "password": "secret123",
>       "pin": "12345",
>   }'

but Xcode asks me to use the syntax below.

```
func loginPressed() {
    let todosEndpoint: String = "https://mydevapi.com/authenticateuser"
    guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
    todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

    let newTodo = "{\"api_key\":\"mykey123\",\"api_secret\":\"asdfg\",\"uniqueid\":\"csd23cdse34ww\",\"password\":\"secret123\",\"pin\":\"12345\"}"

    let jsonTodo: Data
    do {
        jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
        todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
        print(newTodo)
    } catch {
        print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
        return
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {
            guard let receivedTodo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
            return
            }
            print(receivedTodo)
            print("The todo is: " + receivedTodo.description)

            guard let todoID = receivedTodo["id"] as? Int else {
                print("Could not get todoID as int from JSON")
                print(receivedTodo)
                return
            }
            print("The ID is: \(todoID)")
            print(receivedTodo)
        } catch  {
            print("error parsing response from POST on /todos")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

App is crashing - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

2019-01-25 09:37:05.762339+0000 APPTEST[8601:615340] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087f11bb **exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010635f735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001087f1015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105eb2dd5 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 253
    4   APPTEST                           0x000000010588ab5e $S9Bibimoney15LoginControllerC12loginPressedyyF + 2718
    5   APPTEST                           0x000000010588f79c $STA.7 + 28
    6   APPTEST                           0x00000001058924d4 $S9Bibimoney9LoginViewC06handleB0yyF + 132
    7   APPTEST                           0x0000000105892534 $S9Bibimoney9LoginViewC06handleB0yyFTo + 36
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010c876ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010c2b20bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c2b23da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c2b131e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c8b20a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c8b37a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c891394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c9665a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c9691cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108756721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108755f93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010875063f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010874fe11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011047c1dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000010c87581d UIApplicationMain + 140
    23  APPTEST                           0x0000000105896517 main + 71
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108d93575 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

- Expected Status code 200

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? What is the full error message from the crash?

Comment: Have you ever seen this server request is handled properly (some existing web client or something)? Can you record request-response, then record request-response of your new client and compare them?

Comment: Sorry guys, first time posting here. I just edited the post. Thank you. I am sorry @ycnix but I don't know how to do that. How can I do? I just started using these tools, sorry guys.

Comment: With Wireshark for example. Start Wireshark, set its capturing filters (port and host), then access your web service with browser.

Comment: Once your see frames, right click one of the frames and select 'Follow TCP stream'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you do not send what you expect. As it seems you try to JSON-encode a String that "already is" JSON. You should print out the contents of your `jsonTodo` (and you will be surprised how much escapes you will see ..). `JSONSerialization` will *probably* do the right thing if you pass it a `Dictionary`, but it is much more Swifty to perform these kind of conversions through `JSONDecoder` and the `Codeable` protocol.

You should reduce your question to the actual problem at hand in order for people to help. Try to concentrate on creating the correct JSON in your `Data` object, once you get that things will fall into place.

In order to get a concrete answer to your current problem you should amend your question with the contents of `jsonTodo`.